# How to configure CXF JAX-WS server with Blueprint

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

I want to deploy a simple CXF Jax-Ws servier to ServiceMix. It's just one OSGI bundle that has both the service interface and impl class. I need to deploy it to different ServiceMix servers ( version 4.4.1) so I need to change the URL address per server. I want to do the server specific configuration in a Karaf .cfg file and the rest in Blueprint. This doesn't need camel. What should I do in Blueprint? I can't find specific documentation.

Comment: Did you try something at all?

Comment: Why yes I did. I have a web service working without osgi. I'm now converting it to osgi with Spring.

Comment: So what is the problem then? You have a web service and what is stopping you from converting it to OSGi? I have done conversion from web service to OSGi and deployed them successfully into Karaf. I need more details about your problem and only then I would be able to help you.

Comment: The web service builds with the Maven bundle plugin, it passes JUNit tests in Eclipse, I deploy and resolve the bundle in Karaf. Next I need to start and stop the web service. I first tried BundleActivator, strangely, when I added osgi.core Maven dependencies Eclipse still couldn't find the BundleActivator class. I'd prefer to do this with Declarative Services but I can't find any ServiceMix documentation on how to do that. My next choice is Blueprint but I haven't found documentation on how to use it for a bundle that has both the SEI and Impl.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [tutorial about CXF and blueprint in Apache Karaf](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/12/22/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+4+-+CXF+Services+in+OSGi). That should provide you with a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Included is the blueprint configuration I used to configure an "all-in-one" JAX-WS web service using CXF and Blueprint in Karaf.

I also included server-specific properties (as defined in the OSGi Config Admin). The .cfg file in Karaf's `etc` directory would named `com.example.myservice.cfg` and they are accessed in the blueprint file with the `${}` notation. I defined one property named `schema-validation-enabled` (we toggle this value for production environments).

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
                    http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
                    http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
                    http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd">

<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.example.myservice">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<!-- A normal CXF endpoint -->
<jaxws:endpoint id="sampleService" implementor="com.example.myservice.impl.MyServiceImpl"
    endpointName="s:MyServicePort" serviceName="s:MyService" address="/MyService"
    wsdlLocation="/wsdl/MyService.wsdl"
    xmlns:s="http://www.example.com/MyService/SVC/v1">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="${schema-validation-enabled}" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same issue and it was because the bean definition was missing in the OSGi blueprint of the bundle where the Service *belonged*. 
I realized that even though the bean ref definition was present in the OSGi blueprint of the bundle *using* the Service, it is mandatory to define it in it's own bundle blueprint.